# Alternatives to AppBot for contacting App Store reviewer?

Tags: ios, app-store

[AppBot](https://appbot.co/%20%22AppBot) apparently provides a way to contact the reviewer in the Apple App Store to seek more information on their feedback. Since AppBot is a paid option, does anyone know of an alternative free solution for the same?

Regards,

Paddy

Comment: I really doubt there's a way to contact app reviewers in the App Store; there are big privacy issues. On the AppBot website they only mention contacting reviewers in the Play Store.

Comment: OK @Ian, in that case I think I may have misunderstood this line "Appbot provides a really useful tool where they'll attempt to help you discover who the reviewer is on the App Store." in http://savvyapps.com/blog/mobile-app-analytics?utm_campaign=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly&utm_medium=web&utm_source=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_274 - wonder if it means it will show the e-mail ID of the reviewer or just the username?

Comment: I imagine they take the displayed username and try to find a match on other sites. Doesn't sound very reliable to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's **not** possible to contact a person who wrote a review for your app on the Apple App Store. (It's only possible to reply to reviews on Google Play)

What tools like AppBot do is search for the username and **try** to "find" that person on the web. LaunchKit (https://launchkit.io/reviews/) did something similar, but you are no longer able to signup for the service (got bought by Google). But they open sourced all their tools, so you might be possible to get a similar functionality "for free" (https://github.com/launchkit/launchkit)

Comment: Thank you @Oddle, will try to check LaunchKit.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest news since public iOS 10.3 release we will be able to respond app views. Check out this: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10_3.html